# IntelliJ showing "Haxe SDK has no valid root" on linux

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, sdk, fedora, haxe

I'm not sure what's wrong with my Haxe SDK setup in IntelliJ running on Fedora Linux.

I have the SDK pointed to `/usr/bin/`, which is where the executable is located according to the results of "which haxe" in the command line. I'm still relatively new to running linux as my primary OS, but I've managed to get the SDK working on windows with what I believe are the equivalent settings.

I've been searching for a while and haven't found any fixes online. So any help is much appreciated.

Everything works properly from the command line.

[image: Screenshot of SDK Settings]

Comment: Please show the code and/or state the errors. The text on the picture is too small for some people to read. In addition, the text on the image cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well it figures that I solve the problem less than 5 minutes after posting my question, when I had literally been struggling with this for at least 3 hours.

Solution was to add `/usr/share/haxe/std` as a sourcepath in the SDK settings, hopefully this can help out anyone else that runs into the same issue.